# org-ref Error: org-ref-list-index: No catch for tag: --cl-block-nil--, 0 #813

Tags: bibtex, org-ref

On a fresh install of Emacs I am unable to get org-ref to produce citations in my pdfs. I simply get question marks and in Org PDF Latex Output I get a lot of `LaTeX Warning: Citation XXX on page XX undefined on input line XX.`

Doing `C-c ]` works fine and so does `M-x org-ref`. However, if I run `M-x org-ref` after inserting a citation somewhere in the document, I get the following error: `org-ref-list-index: No catch for tag: --cl-block-nil--, 0`. So I wonder if that might have something to do with it.

My org file (thesis.org) and bib file (bibliography.bib) are in the same folder.

**Edit 1**: producing just the .tex file and then running pdflatex, then bibtex then two times pdflatex in terminal according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354218) works. Would still like to have org-ref work within Emacs.

**Edit 2:** Running with the debugger, I get this Backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (no-catch --cl-block-nil-- 2)
  throw(--cl-block-nil-- 2)
  org-ref-list-index("einstein" ("knuthwebsite" "latexcompanion" "einstein"))
  SOME CODE HERE THAT IS TOO LONG TO POST, LOOKS LIKE: #f(compiled-function (link) #<bytecode 0x174a8c1>)((link (:type "cite"...
  org-ref-bad-cite-candidates()
  org-ref()
  funcall-interactively(org-ref)
  call-interactively(org-ref record nil)
  command-execute(org-ref record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "org-ref" "org-ref")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "org-ref" "org-ref")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

- Org-ref version: 20201013.1427
- OS: Ubuntu 20.10
- Emacs version: 26.3

The output of `M-x org-ref` (when it does work) is: (I transcribed this from the screen, so please allow typos)

```
* Bibliography
Using the bibtex files: (bibliography.bib)

* Miscellaneous
org-latex-prefer-user-labels = nil
bibtex-dialect = BibTeX
biblatex is not required.
biblatex is not used.
org-version = 9.4
completion backend = org-ref-helm-bibtex
org-latex-pdf-process is defined as (%latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f %latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f %latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f)
natbib is not required.
natbib is not used.
cleveref is not required.
cleveref is not used.

* Utilities
Check buffer again
```

**thesis.org**

```
* Header

Some text. cite:knuthwebsite

bibliographystyle:unsrt
bibliography:bibliography.bib
```

**bibliography.bib**

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

**init.el**

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
;; Comment/uncomment this line to enable MELPA Stable if desired.  See `package-archive-priorities`
;; and `package-pinned-packages`. Most users will not need or want to do this.
;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(inhibit-startup-buffer-menu nil)
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (helm-swoop org-superstar org-brain org use-package tidal py-autopep8 org-bullets flycheck elpy))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

;; -------------------------------------------------------------
;; org
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-superstar-mode 1)))

;; -------------------------------------------------------------
;; latex
(require 'ox-latex)

(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
      '("mimosis"
         "\\documentclass{mimosis}
         [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
         [PACKAGES]
         [EXTRA]"
     ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}")
     ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
     ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
     ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
     ("\\mboxparagraph{%s}" . "\\mboxparagraph*{%s}")
     ("\\mboxsubparagraph{%s}" . "\\mboxsubparagraph*{%s}")))

;; -------------------------------------------------------------
;; org-ref
(require 'org-ref)

(setq reftex-default-bibliography '("~/test/bibliography.bib"))

;; see org-ref for use of these variables
(setq org-ref-bibliography-notes "~/test/notes.org"
      org-ref-default-bibliography '("~/test/bibliography.bib")
      org-ref-pdf-directory "~/test/papers")

(setq bibtex-completion-bibliography "~/test/bibliography.bib"
      bibtex-completion-library-path "~/test/papers"
      bibtex-completion-notes-path "~/test/helm-bibtex-notes")

;; -------------------------------------------------------------
;; helm
(require 'helm)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'helm-find-files)

;; helm-swoop
(require 'helm-swoop)

(global-set-key (kbd "M-i") 'helm-swoop)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-I") 'helm-swoop-back-to-last-point)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c M-i") 'helm-multi-swoop)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M-i") 'helm-multi-swoop-all)
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "M-i") 'helm-swoop-from-isearch)
(define-key helm-swoop-map (kbd "M-i") 'helm-multi-swoop-all-from-helm-swoop)
(setq helm-multi-swoop-edit-save t)
(setq helm-swoop-use-fuzzy-match t)
```

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce the error. Try setting `debug-on-error` to `t` and  post the backtrace you get (assuming you get one). Can you also try with a very simple init.el (maybe just `(require 'org-ref)``?

Comment: I have now tried this with a minimal init. The Backtrace is posted as Edit 2.

Comment: So try evaluating `(org-ref-list-index "einstein" '("knuthwebsite" "latexcompanion" "einstein"))` in your *scratch* buffer; I get 2 as the answer, but I suspect you are going to get your usual error. Not sure why - yet.

Comment: (would post this as a comment but i don't have enough reputation). I have the same issue and it is still present in GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (snapshot from emacs.ganneff.de) on bullseye/sid (with minimal `min-init.el` as above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pushed a lot of commits to fix issues like these in the last two weeks. The issues were due to differences in dolist, and cl-lib, etc. I think they are all working now.

The answer is probably to update to the latest org-ref, and all the issues should go away. If not, I would consider it a bug in org-ref still and it would be helpful to report it at https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/issues.

Answer (score 1):

[This is not an answer: it's more debugging suggestions to avoid a long comment thread]

I evaluated `(org-ref-list-index "einstein" '("knuthwebsite" "latexcompanion" "einstein"))` in 26.3 and I get `2` there as well: no error (I started with `emacs -q` and initialized the package system by hand in order to load org-ref which I installed from MELPA).

Note that `org-ref-list-index` uses `dolist`.`dolist` in 26.3 is a macro that does not have any advice around it: please confirm with `C-h f dolist RET`. In 28.50.0 however, there is an advice: the doc string says:

```
dolist is a Lisp macro in ‘subr.el’.

(dolist (VAR LIST [RESULT]) BODY...)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 21.1.

This macro has :around advice: ‘cl--wrap-in-nil-block’.

Loop over a list.
Evaluate BODY with VAR bound to each car from LIST, in turn.
Then evaluate RESULT to get return value, default nil.
```

That sounds to me as if there is some incompatibility: it seems that somethings throws `--cl-block-nil--` but `dolist` does not catch it and you end up with the error. In a vanilla 26.3 system, nobody should throw that, but apparently somebody does in your setup. OTOH, in 28.50.0, `dolist` has an advice that I'm guessing adds a catch for that, presumably because somebody does throw it. So you seem to have something that throws that condition but a `dolist` that is incapable of catching it.

BTW, this is mostly guesswork - just in case it wasn't clear :-)

TODO:

- try evaluating `(org-ref-list-index "einstein" '("knuthwebsite" "latexcompanion" "einstein"))` in your `*scratch*` buffer and see if you get the error.
- try the same thing but with `emacs -q -l min-init.el` so as to avoid most of your initializations. You will still need something like this in your min-init.el:

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(require 'org-ref)
```

If you get the error with both of those, something would seem to be curdled in your installation: I would upgrade emacs and start from scratch.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. `C-h f dolist RET` does indeed give me the same doc string as the one you posted. Do you have any idea of where to go from here? Should I get a new version of Emacs?

Comment: Remote debugging is hard :-) I added a few suggestions in the TODO list.